# JasperReports Server (v6.2) Dashboard doesn't work with HTML5 chart report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

**Background:**

Jaspersoft introduced a new generation of Jaspersoft Dashboard in 6.0. The old kind of Dashboard has been renamed as Legacy Dashboard.

I have some Legacy Dashboards in my JasperReports Server. They work fine. However, I am trying to re-generate them in the new Dashboard.

---

**The Issue**

I have a HTML5 chart report as shown below. It works well.

[image]

Moreover, in my Legacy Dashboard, the report also works well.

However, when I created a new kind of Dashboard with the same report, it doesn't work and show me the error as shown below.

I don't know if it is a JasperReports Server 6.2.0 bug, or I did something wrong.

[image]

---

**More Info about the Issue**

Other kinds of report, for example, the traditional plain reports, work well in both the Legacy Dashboard and the new kind of Dashboard.

---

**My JasperReports Server**

- Linux  Red Hat 4.8.2-16
- CPU(s): 2 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
- MemTotal: 7517 MB
- Disk Space: Enough
- Tomcat JVM setting: -Xms2048m -Xmx5500m
- Jaspersoft Server version: Enterprise Version 6.2.0
- Tomcat version: 7.0.65
- PostgreSQL version: 9.3.5
- Browser used: Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Could you add more information about this error?
Do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: I checked the JapserReports Server's logs and Tomcat 7 server's logs (log level ERROR) but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause has been found. We miss a .js extension of the file

jasperserver-pro/optimized-scripts/bower_components/bi-report/src/adhoc/chart/palette/defaultPalette